# "callback is not a function" Node.Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I have a project written in NodeJs with mysql, async.waterfall

I have also implemented the async.waterfall to avoid my recent problem about 'callback is not a function'

but the problem still exist.

here is my async.waterfall

```
async.waterfall([
    function (callback) {
        hold.getEntry(function(data){
            var ref = data.ref;
            id = data.id;
            var message = data.mess;
            json = JSON.parse(message);

            return callback(null, {'ref':ref, 'id':id, 'json':json});
        });
    },
    function (dataa, callback) {
        if(dataa.ref === null){
            callback(null);
        }else{
            hold.checkPositionCandidate(dataa.ref, dataa.id, dataa.json, function(dataaa){
                return callback(null, dataaa);
            });
        }
    },
    function(anoData, callback) {
        console.log(anoData);
        if(anoData === true){

             //the err is here
            hold.getVoterCount(id, json, function(votercount){
                if(votercount == 0){
                } else {
                    console.log('last function');
                }
            });
        } else {
        }
    }
], function (err, results) {
   // When finished execute this
});
```

and this is my getVotercount function

```
function getVoterCount (id, callback){
    pool.getConnection(function(err, con){
        con.query("select total_voters as tv from pollwatcher_view where party_id = ?", [id], function(err, rows){
        setTimeout(function(){

            //this callback is not a function
            callback(null, {'count':rows[0].tv});
            console.log(rows);
        }, 2000);
        }); 
    });
}
```

I am very close to finish my project but that err makes me frustrate. Please someone help me.

Comment: So you are calling the function with three arguments...

Comment: ... so change `hold.getVoterCount(id, json, function(votercount){...})` to `hold.getVoterCount(id, function(votercount){..})`

Comment: @elclanrs yes, i have a json variable outside

Comment: @NikolayErmakov you are my savior! I didn't see that. Thankyou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be calling

```
hold.getVoterCount(id, json, function(votercount){
                if(votercount == 0){
                } else {
                    console.log('last function');
                }
            });
```

but your getVoterCount function is defined with only 2 expected parameters.  I'd suggest trying to only pass in 2 parameters:

```
hold.getVoterCount(id, function(votercount){
            if(votercount == 0){
            } else {
                console.log('last function');
            }
        });
```